# How to add a LinearLayout as a system_alert using the window manager

Tags: android

I've followed the following tutorial on how to add a simple view (in the tutorial its an image) above all other windows using the window manager.

http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

It works like a charm when I'm trying to use it with the ImageView. When I'm trying to do it with a ViewGroup subclass, such as a linear layout, nothing is displayed and I'm not sure why.

Here is my code

```
package com.example.servicedialogexample;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloService extends IntentService {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private LinearLayout m_viwAlert;
    private ImageView im;

    public HelloService()
    {
        super("HelloService");

        m_viwAlert = null;
        windowManager = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        m_viwAlert = new LinearLayout(this);
        im = new ImageView(this);
        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);


        WindowManager.LayoutParams params1 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params1.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

        ((LinearLayout)m_viwAlert).addView(im, params1);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        windowManager.addView(m_viwAlert, params);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (m_viwAlert != null)
        {
            windowManager.removeView(m_viwAlert);
        }

    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly here...

Thanks in advance for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion here; sorry.

I copied your code over and tried it for myself to see if I could help. I put some logs in onCreate and onDestroy and it turns out the onDestroy was being called instantly.

Now I don't know much about IntentServices myself so but I started it using

```
startService(context, HelloService.class);
```

Maybe you should check your code isn't doing this because the thing is; I changed it from IntentService to just Service; and well your code worked a treat.

Happy Investigating; I wish I could have been more help.